# CSS pseudo class won't work when normal class is set from javascript, under FF

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, pseudo-class

I have `p.first_p:first-letter` in my stylesheet, as I checked, it works well when class `first_p` is set in HTML. Problems start when I use javascript to find elements and then set their class.

Under Chrome and Opera it works fine (I need to check IE 8 and 9, and FF3).

FF 5.01 changes the class, but still pseudo class setting doesn't affect the element.

It seems that FF needs to 'refresh' css settings of element before pseudo class starts working, so I made rather dirty workaround - script replaces affected node with its clone.

Is there a better way to solve that issue? Some way to make FF recalculate everything it knows about node? Also that workaround isn't enough for IE 7.

Edit: yeah, pseudo-element not pseudo-class, my bad

Comment: Hnh, that's weird... and here's a [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pvEDY/) to corroborate.

Comment: `:first-letter` is a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to not use javascript?

I'm guessing that you're applying first_p to the first paragraph of particular elements.
It possible for you to use the :first-child selector instead?

I'm not sure if this will work, but you could try something like the following, assuming you want to apply this to children of divs with class "copy"

```
.copy p:first-child:first-letter{
  color: #abcdef; /* or whatever */
}
```

[this definitely works](http://jsfiddle.net/pvEDY/2/) and you don't need javascript, except for crappy old IE.

Alternatively you could try this:

```
.element p:first-letter{
  font-size: 20px;
}

.element p + p:first-letter{
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

This css makes any paragraph that is not preceded by another paragraph have a styled first letter. Would that solve your problem?

Wait, you want it to work in Firefox. Try this:

```
.element p:first-of-type:first-letter{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

It selects the first matching element. The :first-of-type pesudo-element is supported by Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari according to [SitePoint's page for :first-of-type](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstoftype)

Comment: I was using it, but p is not always first child, so it won't work always.

Comment: would it work as `.copy:first-child:first-letter{}`? Or can you provide a sample/typical html snippet that you're working with?

Comment: I've edited in an alternative solution that might do the trick.

Comment: I'm using `.article_content p:first-child:first-letter` now. But since `p` is not always a first child of `.article_content` it won't always work.As far as I know there is no way to select that `p` only with CSS.

Comment: Not all that I don't want to mark as first paragraphs are directly followed by `p` so `.element p + p:first-letter` won't help me too :(

Comment: `p:first-of-type:first-letter` is interesting... what browsers support that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant this bit: .element p:first-of-type:first-letter

Comment: Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera. You could set it up so only IE uses the .js, and every other major browser should work fine with css.

Comment: Hm. I checked and it works nicely. Still, my workaround script isn't enough for IE. Wladimir solution seems to work well, but I'm not sure how to implement it inside loop. If you could just look at his answer and my comments I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a bug. A possible work-around would be changing the `display` style of the element. Unfortunately, this needs to be done delayed, after the previous style change applied:

```
element.className = 'first-class';
element.style.display = 'inline';
setTimeout(function(){
  element.style.display = '';
}, 0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pvEDY/3/

Comment: Hm... childReplace with clone seems simpler than that.

Comment: @korda: I was looking for a way to trigger a restyle without creating a different node.

Comment: Now when I tried it, I found another problem. I have loop in which I change nodes. Variables in context in which I created function change during loop iterations, so when function is called it affects only last node.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8253